# Rename initialize method to the more friendly init

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

What would be **the best way** to rename the long **'initialize'** method in ruby to something like *Objective-C* **'init'**, so that inside any class definition we could just say

```
def init
end
```

instead of

```
def initialize 
end
```

?

**UPDATE**

I want to create an init that acts as initialize and takes arguments and blocks that gets passed to Object.new(*args, &block) I need a typical initialize method called init which .new calls instead of initialize so that I can pass arguments and blocks through it to the original one. Um looking for something that hooks with the object creation and initialize itself. Some sort of a call back.

**UPDATE 2**

I've turned the correct answer into a gem check it out...

https://rubygems.org/gems/new_init

Comment: What's the reason for it? You never call `initialize`, you call `new` to create objects.

Comment: The reason is to modify the initializer method name, so it would be more flexible to create it in new classes and as a shortcut also

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way, by far, would be to not do it. The extra 6 characters won't kill you, and are well worth having in order to keep your ruby idiomatic. However, if you really wanted to, you could do it with monkey patching:

```
# Monkey patch BasicObject (which your class will inherit from) such that
# it's initialize method just passes on params to init
class BasicObject
  def initialize(*args)
    init(*args) if respond_to? :init
  end
end

class MyClass
  def init(test1, test2)
    puts "Params are: #{test1}, #{test2}"
  end

  def say_hello
    puts "Hello from a class that uses init rather than initialize"
  end
end

x = MyClass.new('Hello', 'World')
x.say_hello
```

Just to re-iterate, it's a bad idea. Don't do it.

Comment: Its bad in your point of view, but not bad in mine, thanks a lot for your thoughts, and Hey, the reason we all love ruby is that its so damn flexible.

Comment: WHY is it a "bad idea" ?

I can guess that there would be slowdown whenever a new class was instantied, but how much of a slowdown.

What other reasons?

Comment: It's a bad idea because it breaks an established convention, and conventions in coding are valuable.

Another dev stumbles across this code later, and sees an init method.
What's it do? Sounds like it probably initialises the class? But I thought in Ruby that was always done with initialize? (Googles it...) Yep, it's initialise in Ruby. Let's try it out... MyClass.new()... oh yep, init DOES get called! But how??? (Googles again... "is init alternative to initialise in Ruby") Hmm... nope, I know that init is getting called, but WHY is this working!?!?!

Comment: Hours later of pulling hair out they find the monkey-patching trick, and wonder what on earth the original dev was thinking and why they decided to break a convention that was working just fine for every other ruby developer in the world.

Answer (score 4):

It's impossible to do this without changing the language specification.

But first, I will show you what *is* possible.

`#initialize` is called by `Class#new`. `Class#new` basically looks like this:

```
class Class
  def new(*args, &block)
    obj = allocate
    obj.initialize(*args, &block)
    obj
  end
end
```

Except that `initialize` is `private` by default, so you *actually* need to do this:

```
class Class
  def new(*args, &block)
    obj = allocate
    obj.__send__(:initialize, *args, &block)
    obj
  end
end
```

Now, it's immediately obvious what you need to do to change the name of the method: just monkeypatch `Class#new` to call `init` instead of `initialize`:

```
class Class
  def new(*args, &block)
    obj = allocate
    obj.init(*args, &block)
    obj
  end
end
```

Boom! You're done.

*However*, this is *not* equivalent! Note how I said above that `initialize` is `private` by default? That's "magic"! The name `initialize` is special in that unlike other methods, which are `public` by default, a method named `initialize` is `private` by default:

```
class Foo
  def initialize; end
  def init; end
end

Foo.private_instance_methods(false)
#=> [:initialize]

Foo.public_instance_methods(false)
#=> [:init]
```

This is part of the Ruby Language Specification and cannot be expressed from within Ruby.

Note also that now that you have monkeypatched `Class#new` to call `init` instead of `initialize`, you need to rename every single existing `initialize` method in the system, otherwise, they won't get called!

```
ObjectSpace.each_object(Module).
  select {|m| m.instance_methods(false).include?(:initialize) }.
  each do |m|
    m.alias_method :init, :initialize
  end

class Class
  def new(*args, &block)
    obj = allocate
    obj.init(*args, &block)
    obj
  end
end

ObjectSpace.each_object(Module).
  select {|m| m.instance_methods(false).include?(:initialize) }.
  each do |m|
    m.remove_method :initialize
  end
```

This code will almost surely crash any real-world program, because reliance on the name `initialize` is just too deeply baked into existing Ruby code, and Ruby culture.

Comment: Your answer is good, but the chosen one actually doesn't change the language specs if you encapsulate that logic inside the conditional respond_to? statement... check out how I implemented this on my gem new_init https://github.com/a7madx7/new_init

Comment: I don't see how you achieve that `init` is automatically `private`.

Comment: @a7madx7 I've seen what you did. Now you only need to include one nasty obfuscated back-door into your code :)

Answer (score 1):

```
class Object
  #alias_method :native_initialize, :initialize
  def initialize
    #native_initialize
    init if respond_to? :init
  end
end

class Duck
  def init
    p "QUA QUA"
  end
end

Duck.new
```

Comment: I think this will cause arity issues for methods that call `super`. Changing `Object#initialize`'s signature to `def initialize(*args, &block)` might be a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

A code-less `initialize` method? Just do nothing.

```
class Foo
 # no meaningful initialize
end
```

Comment: your not getting me here right, i want to create an init that acts as initialize and takes arguments and blocks that gets passed to Object.new(*args, &block)

I need a typical initialize method called init which .new calls instead of initialize so that I can pass arguments and blocks through it to the original one. Um looking for something that hooks with the object creation and initialize itself. Some sort of a call back.